# How can i make vehicles do random routes in SUMO?

Tags: sumo

I need to make vehicles do random routes, not random speed or acceleration, random edges that he moves to.

I tried using "RNG" and "random" to see if caused any effect and it didn't.Also tried searching for it and couldn't find anything about the issue.I'm on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To constantly change the vehicles' routes, you would have to use [TraCI](https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/traci._vehicle.html). You can use either one of the following ways:

1. You can parse and store the **net-file** to understand how the edges are connected to each other and update the vehicle's route using `setRoute`.
2. Pre-define multiple possible routes and pre-load it using TraCI or in the **routes/additional file** and change the vehicle's route using `setRouteID`
3. **Easiest** of all is to use the command `moveToXY` in the TraCI package. When using this command, you can change the vehicle's edge for each time step (by setting the `keepRoute` parameter to 0). This forces the vehicle to change its route, however, now the route consists of only ONE single edge (to which the vehicle was moved). Do this repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

The way we found to do this was by using the random_trips.py script.

We've created a vType distribution file and before every single SUMO execution, we execute the random_trips.py on this vType distribution to generate a new random route file.

As random_trips.py creates random routes, it works like a charm.